# How to put an underscore in a page name?

Tags: mediawiki

I am wondering how to put an underscore in a page name in MediaWiki. I know it's possible, because there are [a few articles with an underscore in their name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Articles_with_underscores_in_the_title) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done using the [`{{DISPLAYTITLE:…}}` magic word](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Technical_metadata).

Comment: It works but in the _CategoryTree_ the page still ignores the _underscore_.

Comment: @JConstantine That's probably an issue with the CategoryTree plugin then - feel free to report it!